# Dodge Effect Fix? (FNF Psych Engine)

Tags: haxe

```
            case 'Dodge': //hahahahahahahaha beat that demo
            new FlxTimer().start(0.1, function(tmr:FlxTimer)
                {
                    var warning = new FlxText(0, 0, 0, 'Press Space Bar Now!', 32);
                    warning.cameras = [camOther];
                    warning.setFormat(Paths.font("vcr.ttf"), 24, FlxColor.WHITE, CENTER, FlxTextBorderStyle.OUTLINE, FlxColor.BLACK);
                    warning.screenCenter(X);
                    warning.size = 50;
                    warning.screenCenter(Y);
                    warning.updateHitbox();
                    add(warning);
                });

                new FlxTimer().start(0.6, function(tmr:FlxTimer)
                    {
                        if (FlxG.keys.justPressed.SPACE)
                            {
                                health = 1;
                                boyfriend.playAnim('dodge', true); //woosh
                                FlxG.sound.play(Paths.sound('dodge')); //stab
                                remove(warning);
                                warning.destroy();
                            }
                            else {
                                health -= 2;
                                vocals.volume = 0;
                                doDeathCheck(true); //dead noises
                            };
                    });
```

so it does it but it wont detect space bar being hit
i need it so it will detect the space bar being hit
i am not sure what i did wrong or what i did but it just goes to game over

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would Use lua ( not using source ) Since there is no offical event sorry im a Psych engine nerd- I made 2 engines so  i would say make a lua event with it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Since Making events is hard ( i had help with mine engine )